# NGEN queue 1 never runs

Tags: .net, ngen

I'm NGEN-ing some dlls in my application. I'd like to do this as part of my installer, but I'd like it to occur in the background as there's no need to make the user wait for this to complete.

If I run the following command it generates the native image properly:

```
ngen.exe install "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\MyLib.dll"
```

However, if I specify a queue, the native image **does not gets created**:

```
ngen.exe install "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp\MyLib.dll" /queue:1
```

The native image service simply never runs. If, after I've added the dll to the queue, I run `ngen.exe executeQueuedItems`, then it goes ahead and creates the native image of my dll.

In the [ngen docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator) it says:

> Priority 1 - Native images are generated and installed immediately, without
>   waiting for idle time.

This does not seem to be the case on two machines I tried it on. Unless I kick it off with `ngen eqi` the ngen'ing just never happens. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to this after a while. Figured out finally that it does indeed run, but it starts in a few minutes, not right away.